# Replacing one variable with another variable in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace one variable with another interactively with sed -i. It seems to be very easy but for some reason is not working.

Let's say I have a file which has 1 column:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
.
.
```

I want to assign these values into a variable and make an arithmetic operation on them which will be the new variable and then replace the previous variable with the new one. Something like the following:

```
for i in `awk '{print $1}' file.dat`;
do
        j=`echo $i | awk '{print ($1)*0.66}'`;
        sed -i "s/$i/$j/g" file.dat;
done
```

I expect to get the following:

```
0.66
1.32
1.98
2.64
3.3
3.96
4.62
5.28
```

But, here's what I get:

```
0.3.963.96
1.1.95.282
1.95.28
2.3.964
3.3
3.96
4.62
5.28
```

I know it's probably something very simple. But, my brain doesn't work today. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When `$i` is `1`, the first line of the file changes to `0.66`.

Then when `$i` is `6`, it replaces each of those `6` characters with `3.96`, so that line becomes `0.3.963.96`.

You need to change the regexp so it only matches entire lines:

```
sed -i "s/^$i\$/$j/g" file.dat;
```

`^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the line.

There doesn't seem to be much reason to used `sed` in this, though, you can do it entirely with `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1 * 0.66}' file.dat > newfile.dat
```

If you're using GNU awk it has an extension that can be used to modify the file in place.

```
gawk -i inplace '{print $1 * 0.66}' file.dat
```

Comment: The single-pass approach with `awk` is much better, because it's both less fragile and faster. When you process one line at a time, you don't risk having something intended to affect just one line affect others as well (as in this case). It's also much faster, because e.g. with a 100-line file, you just make 100 changes each to one line; with the original version, it'd make 100 changes, but try to apply each of those to all 100 lines, meaning it's doing 10,000 operations (9,900 of them pointless and potentially wrong).

Comment: I do understand both of your answers. Yes, if it was just scaling the numbers, I always do it by using awk. However, I am ultimately trying to grep a certain pattern in a file which consists of a number, scale that number and replace that number with the new value in that file. for example, I would save a variable "var=`grep "pattern" file | awk '{print $3}'`" , assuming the 3rd column has the vaules and then do the scaling operation and replace var. That's why I was trying to use sed. Using sed the way I explained, gives me "sed: -e expression". I will try the way you explained and see.

Comment: You should still be able to do it using `awk`. It has regular expressions, you can concatenate strings with it, etc.